# Problem on accessing Allitems.aspx, "Sorry something went wrong"

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, asp.net, windows-server-2012-r2

When I try to access a link from our portal company website (SharePoint), for example `AttendancePlaces/AllItems.aspx`, it asks for admin credentials as normal but after that I get an error *"Sorry something went wrong"*.
[image]

In the log files, it says that the "Application error when access /AttendancePlaces/AllItems.aspx, Error the list doesn't exist with the current url.

I tried to access the list via SharePoint and says the samething
(the list is the 1 that has 17 items and hasn't been modified by 15 months)
[image]

It was working fine a few days ago, hasn't been modified in 15 months

Comment: Please share the related CorrelationID from ULS-Log for further investigation.

Comment: Please add more information (e.g. the logs as mentioned above would be beneficial). Also: have the links worked before? Does the URL look correct? If you navigate to the path via site's site contents, can you access it? Are you 100% certain the /AttendancePlaces/ is available to you (i.e. confirm permission settings)? Are the view pages (AllItems.aspx etc.) checked in and published to a major version? Anything else possibly relevant to be added?

Comment: This is the error log found

Comment: @user3656060, change your question with error log entries found by Correlation ID. By default *.log files placed in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS. You may use UlsViewer for it (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020)

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by several reasons. Please provide more information to narrow down this issue:

1. Whether this issue happened in other lists/libraries/SharePoint pages? Check the existing lists/library or create new one.
2. If this happened in all site, go to IIS manger, check if the web application started, and you can restart and check again.
3. Switch to other users to access this link and check if the issue exists.
4. Based on the Correlation ID to check the ULS log( C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS) to get more error message related with this issue.

Comment: I updated my question, if you please can check again, added a few prints to help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to site contents and from there go to the list settings.

Check if you are able to go the site settings, if yes,

then create another view see. Sometimes the allitems view gets corrupted and we have to create another view.